# Unit Test vs. e2e Test vs. REST Test

Tags: angularjs, rest, unit-testing, e2e-testing

I am building an angularjs application that fetches data from a REST resource. The REST server has its own e2e tests (http requests that actually make changes in the database with real sample data) and in front-end I am using karma to run the unit tests in my code.

With front-end unit testing I can test controllers, directives, services... and I think almost any scenario. The back-end doesn't really need to be tested again in the front-end tests.

Templates and such things can also easily be also unit tested using selectors and checking visibility, availability, or whatever you need.

So what is angularjs e2e testing for? Is it necessary if I already have the back-end tested or I am missing something?

Comment: Who says you have to test backend in e2e? E2e can be mocked the same way as units, see ngMockE2E.

Comment: But then why would you want to repeat same tests in unit and in e2e?

Comment: They would be the same in theory, written by theoretical programmers. In practice the app can be broken when all unit tests are green, and vice versa.